# Как сделать чтобы не переданные в шаблон jinja2 элементы, не создавались?

Tags: django, jinja2

base.html

```
<h2 class="mt-3 mb-3">
    {% block main_title %}

    {% endblock %}
</h2>
```

В некоторые из наследуемых от этого шаблона файлы, я буду передавать `main_title`. А в некоторые нет, как сделать чтобы `h2` создавался только там где я передам `main_title`.

Comment: Может, стоит перенести тег `<h2>` во включаемый шаблон? При таком подходе проблема отпадает сама собой.

Comment: Тогда каждый раз нужно будет передавать в шаблон `<h2>`. Это нормально?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что у Вас очень много шаблонов с таким тегом (но не все) и трудно прописывать его в каждый? Тогда это интересный вопрос.

Comment: Как раз это я имею ввиду. Я думал есть какой-то способ проверить передаю ли я в шаблон данные или нет

Comment: Способ то есть. Например, с помощью `{% if ... %}...{% else %}...{% endif %}`. Но это некрасиво. К тому же, я пока не знаю, куда рекомендовать это вставить и стоит ли вовсе рекомендовать.

Comment: Да про `if` я знаю. Но как его в такой ситуации использовать непонятно